# How to make a page that looks like this mockup?

Tags: html, css

Below are images of my mockup and my attempt to implement it. There are quite a few problems.

- The Header isn't centered
- I have no idea how to place Button1 to the left of the top-right justified text
- Is there a better way to place the upper-left text to the right of the image than just hard coding the margin based on the image size?
- I also have no idea how to place the text area so that it fills the middle of the div, and aligns as desired.

When I tried to post my html and css in here, all the tags got stripped out. So below are images of my code.

```css
.outer_border {
     border: 1px solid black;
     width: 600px;
     height: 500px;
     position: relative;
    }
    
    .inner_border {
     border: 3px solid black;
     width: 400px;
     height: 300px;
     top: 10px;
     right: 10px;
     position: absolute;
    }
    
    .image {
     border: 1px solid black;
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     top: 5px;
     left: 5px;
     position: absolute;
    }
    
    .upper_left_text {
     top: 5px;
     /*is this a smart way to position to the right of the image?*/
     left: 60px;
     position: absolute;
    }
    
    .the_header {
     top: 5px;
     text-align: center;
     position: absolute;
    }
    
    .button1 {
     top: 5px;
     right: 50px;
     position: absolute;
    }
    
    .button2 {
     bottom: 5px;
     right: 5px;
     width: 80px;
     height: 60px;
     position: absolute;
    }
    
    .text_area {
     /*I have no idea how to position this*/
    }
    .upper_right_text {
     top: 5px;
     /*is this a smart way to position to the right of the image?*/
     right: 5px;
     position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<div class="outer_border">
       <div class="inner_border">
        <!--just use a div to represent the image -->
        <div class ="image">
        </div>
        <span class="upper_left_text">
         some text
        </span>
        <!-- this isn't centered? -->
        <h2 class="the_header">
         Header
        </h2>
        <!-- how do I place this to the left of the text? -->
        <button class="button1">Button</button>
        <span class="upper_right_text">
         some text
        </span>
        <button class="button2">Button 2</button>
        <textarea class="text_area">Text Area</textarea>
       </div>
      </div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do __not__ post screen shots of your code - post the code itself. The only way I have to reproduce this is manually retyping all your HTML and CSS, which I don't have any inclination to do. If you want to post code format it with the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: I had tried with the code format, I thought the preview was not showing tags. I edited the post with the code. Thanks.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of position absolute going on. Why? Is there a reason you are using a `TextArea` input element? How exactly do you want the header centered? Within the inner boarder? Between the text on the left and the button on the right?

Comment: You may want to use floats or a grid for your layout instead of position absolute.

Comment: The text area is required, as there will be text input, and it would be best if it was organized as depicted in the mockup. As far as the absolutely positioning, possibly I'm using that incorrectly, any suggestions for how I could better implement the mockup?

Comment: I'm guessing you're just learning CSS. Read up about the box model, margins & padding (and the difference between them), the different ways of positioning elements. I suggest you start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started